# Detecting outlying instances from probability estimates

Tags: machine-learning, outliers, anomaly-detection, calibration

Say I have a binary classification model that is able to produce (posterior) probability estimates. I check whether these probabilities are calibrated and I evaluate using a metric that describes its ability to discriminate, e.g. ROC AUC. The data I am using is relatively imbalanced (1 positive: 10 negatives)

I would like to take a closer look at instances for which my model produces a high probability of not being part of class $C$, but I know are part of class $C$. Does it make sense to draw conclusions about this instance, e.g. that this is an anomaly ('outlier')? Does this depend on the ROC AUC and if so, to what extent?

Comment: You can use [boosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boosting_(machine_learning)) so that your classifier would by itself adapt to the misclassified cases during the learning process.